# Jest - testing try/catch

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test this class method:

```
get () {
  try {
    return 'value'
  } catch (e) {
    return 'value2'
  }
}
```

with:

```
test('the get method retrieves value', () => {
  const value = MyClass.get()
  expect(value).toBe('value')
})
```

My test coverage shows I have tested the `try` part of the method but not the `catch` part.

How can I cover the `catch` part?

Comment: Never used jest before, but here's something I found https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2129 where somebody does it using async/await that will fail causing the catch to trigger?

Comment: I guess in this version you can't. You have only return `value`, so it redundant to test Javascript feature `try{} catch(e){}`.

Comment: Do you have some method inside the `try{}`? If yes, you can mock it and throw an error on purpose.
Because in your current version, you're trying to test Javascript implementation and not your code.

Answer (score 21):

You can test the catch part by wrapping the function call in a `try catch` block in your test **AND** expecting an assertion. Without expecting an assertion a run of the test that doesn't cause an error will still pass.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#error-handling

```
test('the fetch fails with an error', async done => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  try {
    await fetchData();
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e).toMatch('error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the expectation inside setImmediate() or process.nextTick() as:

```
test('the fetch fails with an error', async => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  setImmediate(() => {
   expect(fetchData).toMatch('error');
  });
});
```